# Azure .NET SDK 2.9.6 Visual Studio Download

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to download the Azure .NET SDK 2.9.6 but all the Microsoft links seem to be dead.

I have tried the Web Platform Installer and this fails with 404 errors, the manual download link returns 'sorry this download is no longer available' page.

Does anybody know where this version can now be downloaded from?

Cheers

Comment: For VS 2019, https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/1888#issuecomment-485963966
Also confirmed here, https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/1888